# Python AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'wirte'

Tags: python, youtube

Im learning python from thenewboston series on youtube. This is from tutorial 24 Downloading Files from the Web. I have written the same program as on the video:

```
from urllib import request

goog_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?
key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv'


def download_stock_data(csv_url):
   response = request.urlopen(csv_url)
   csv = response.read()
   csv_str = str(csv)
   lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
   dest_url = r'goog.csv'
   fx = open(dest_url, "w")
   for line in lines:
      fx.wirte(line + "\n")
   fx.close()

download_stock_data(goog_url)
```

And yet i get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):line 18, in <module>
    download_stock_data(goog_url)

line 14, in download_stock_data
    fx.wirte(line + "\n")
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'wirte'
```

[This is the video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjwWzBiAMck&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAcbMi1sH6oAMk4JHw91mC_&index=24)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That message looks pretty explicit to me. The library module is doing its best to tell you that the function isn't called `wirte()` but `write()`. Only, it can't guess you mean `write()`.

*Edit for Python 3.10:*

Things have changed since this answer was posted. Considerable work has been done to improve CPython's error messages. In response to this error you will now see:

```
AttributeError: type object '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no attribute 'wirte'. Did you mean: 'write'?
```

If you are a beginner who is using an earlier version of Python for no better reason than inertia, consider installing 3.10 just to get these more helpful messages. You can safely install several Python versions side by side (for example, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10).